# String Type Value Member and Display Member in VB.NET Combobox with manually filled data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, combobox, save

I want to store C and D from selected combobox item which is manually feed data "C|Credit, D|Debit". Followint is my code for that

`FillCombosWithValueMDisplayM(m01OpnCrDr, "C|Credit,D|Debit")`
'Calling in form_load

but when I collect data from various control on Form then that time combobox returns 'Nothing'.

I tried the following coding

Following sub to fill manually data to combo is in common module:

```
Sub FillCombosWithValueMDisplayM(CtrlCombo As ComboBox, CommaSepVDPair As String)
       
        Dim pairs() = CommaSepVDPair.Split(",")
        For Each pair As String In pairs
            Dim KeyVal() = pair.Split("|")
            Dim newItem As New With {.Value = KeyVal(0).ToString, .Display = KeyVal(1).ToString}
            CtrlCombo.Items.Add(newItem)
        Next

        CtrlCombo.ValueMember = "Value"
        CtrlCombo.DisplayMember = "Display"

End Sub
```

Now there is other common function that Collects the data from various control on form (winform).
There I check Control type and datatype of field refine the data and add to keyvalue pair.

So, the Common CollectFormData Function is as below (partial). Where I detect m01OpnCrDr combobox and try to get value C (if credit is selected) or D (if Debit is selected) to store that C or D to database field.
But Combobox return 'Nothing'.

Function to Collect Form Data:

```
Function CollectFormData(frm As Form, tbl As DataTable)
        'Function CollectFormData(frm As Form, FieldList As List(Of String)) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim FormDataDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim CtlType As Type
        Dim CtrlArray As Control()
        Dim Ctrl As Control
        Dim fldname As String
        Dim FldType As OleDb.OleDbType
        Dim CtlValuePlaceHolder As Object

        For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
            fldname = row("COLUMN_NAME")
            FldType = row("DATA_TYPE").ToString

            If fldname = "ID" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                CtrlArray = frm.Controls.Find(fldname, True)

                If CtrlArray.Count > 0 Then
                    Ctrl = CtrlArray(0)
                    CtlType = Ctrl.GetType

                    Select Case CtlType
                        Case GetType(TextBox)
                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, TextBox).Text, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                        Case GetType(ComboBox) **'(here combobox m01OpnCrDr returns Nothing)**
                            'CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, ComboBox).SelectedValue, FldType)
                            Dim selectedValue As Object = TryCast(Ctrl, ComboBox).SelectedValue

                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(selectedValue, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                            'CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(selectedValue, FldType)
                            'FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                        Case GetType(C1.Win.Calendar.C1DateEdit)
                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, C1.Win.Calendar.C1DateEdit).Value, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                        Case GetType(CheckBox)
                            If TryCast(Ctrl, CheckBox).Checked Then
                                CtlValuePlaceHolder = True
                            Else
                                CtlValuePlaceHolder = False
                            End If
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                        Case GetType(DateTimePicker)

                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, DateTimePicker).Value, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                        Case GetType(C1.Win.Calendar.C1DateEdit)

                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, C1.Win.Calendar.C1DateEdit).Value, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)


                        Case GetType(MaskedTextBox)
                            CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, MaskedTextBox).Text, FldType)
                            FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)

                    End Select

                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return FormDataDict

End Function
```

Comment: Try this : `Dim selectedValue As string = TryCast(Ctrl, ComboBox).Selecteditem.Value`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then it throws error about row, some "row is not set" or something like that. but finally. I changed my method and adapt DATATABLE as combo source. and it works.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I got the solution. Now I am not filling combobox with manual data feed. Instead now I use DATATABLE. I gave data table as source to combobox and it works. In manually adding items to combobox with property (value and display), property does not set properly and it does not treated as row.

so the best way is to create data table and source it to combobox.
My changed code is as below.

```
Sub CreateCRDRDataTable()
    'gCRDRDataTable is global variable 
    gCRDRDataTable = New DataTable
    gCRDRDataTable.Columns.Add("K", GetType(String))
    gCRDRDataTable.Columns.Add("V", GetType(String))

    gCRDRDataTable.Rows.Add("C", "Credit")
    gCRDRDataTable.Rows.Add("D", "Debit")

End Sub
```

Then fix sub to fill CRDRcombo whenever required.

```
Sub FillCRDRCombo(CtrlCombo As ComboBox)
    CtrlCombo.DataSource = gCRDRDataTable
    CtrlCombo.ValueMember = "K"
    CtrlCombo.DisplayMember = "V"
End Sub
```

Then in data collection from form it works fine. it gets value (either C or D)
following is the code:

```
Case GetType(ComboBox)
                        CtlValuePlaceHolder = CNulls(TryCast(Ctrl, ComboBox).SelectedValue, FldType)
                        FormDataDict.Add(fldname, CtlValuePlaceHolder)
```

**My Problem solved**